# How to get a html tag's Property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a html tag's Property from chrome's 'inspect element' window, I'm using jQuery.

[image: Chrome inspect Property]

I already tried the following codes below

```
$("img#picture").prop("offsetTop");
```

and

```
$("img#picture").offset().top;
```

and

```
$("img#picture").attr("offsetTop");
```

None of them returns 260, which is what I want, they either return undefined or 0. And yes I put them under `$(document).ready(function() {...})`; so that it waits for the image to load then execute the command.

Comment: the only thing i can think is that your element isn't displayed : "  jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for margins set on the <html> document element.

While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering tree and thus has a position that is undefined." src : http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: and make sure there every `img` tag has unique `id` for it

Comment: This isn't the cause of your issue, but it's worth pointing out that your selector `img#picture` is unnecessarily complex, if you're selecting an element by its ID, you never need any other details (as there can only ever be one element with that ID) so `#picture` is enough.

Comment: All of the methods you've described in the question work fine. Check the console for errors and ensure you've loaded jQuery in the page properly and are running your code within a document.ready event handler.

Answer (score 2):

use the native element property:

```
$("img#picture")[0].offsetTop
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Comment: If the OPs examples aren't working  (when they should) this won't either.

Comment: Hmmm, Sorry but `console.log($("#picture")[0].offsetTop);` still shows `0` on console, I'll try the others

Answer (score 0):

It's times like these where you should ask yourself if you should use vanilla Javascript or jQuery.

In any case:

```
// vanilla JS
let offsetTop = document.querySelector("img#picture").offsetTop;
console.log(offsetTop);

// jQuery
let offsetTop = $("img#picture")[0].offsetTop;
console.log(offsetTop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are better places to call your function

```
<body onload="script();">
or

document.onload = function ...
or even

window.onload = function ...
```

Jquery:

var image = $( "img" );
var offset = image.offset();

console.log("left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );

JS:

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
var topPos = d.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

OffsetTop is not an HTML attribute. It is the property of an object. Jquery does not return object property. It only returns DOM node.

Using vanilla

```
var a = document.querySelector("img#picture");
console.log(a[0].offsetTop);
```

Using jQuery

```
var a = $("img#picture");
console.log(a.offsetTop);
```